# Get all elements of type in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

My editor contains custom elements, created like this:

```js
this.editor.model.change( writer => {
    const id = `a${ Math.random().toString().replace('.', '') }`;

    const autocomplete = writer.createElement( 'autocomplete', { 'data-id': id );

    this.editor.model.insertContent( autocomplete );
} );
```

I want to get all 'autocomplete' elements at a later time in my plugin so I can read their content (they're editable elements).

Is there something like `querySelectorAll('autocomplete')` for the model of the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using `range.getWalker`.

```js
const findNodes = function(writer, type, root) {
    const nodes = [];
    const range = writer.createRangeIn( root );

    for ( const value of range.getWalker({ ignoreElementEnd: true }) ) {
        const node = value.item;

        if ( node.is( type ) ) {
            nodes.push(node);
        }
    }

    return nodes;
};

this.editor.model.change( writer => {
    const autocompletes = findNodes(writer, 'autocomplete', this.editor.model.document.getRoot());
} );
```